# Droppable doesn't attach quickly enough to dynamically generated element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This seems like a really annoying bug I have been trying to solve for days. I am making a sortable list. When I click and drag grey item and I hover over the red I need a spacer to show up below it so I can drop it in the newly shown spacer. I try to bind a draggable over the spacer (so I know if the user drops it onto it) but I just can't get the spacer to recognise when it has something 'over it' unles >>>> and here is the gotcha while I drag and hold and move my element to the side of the screen.

To recreate :

1. Click and hold the grey tab
2. Drag it over the red (at this point the yellow spacer shows)
3. Drag it onto the yellow but don't let go of the mouse (notice nothing writes to the console).

[image]

Now repeat the experiement but before going over the yellow spacer wiggle the draggable grey item at the side of the screen now go over the yellow spacer and hey presto it detects it and writes a message to the console which means the code has worked. Does anybody know what the hell is going on? I have been stuck on it for days!

The code:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 30,
    stop: function () {
        $('.spacer').removeClass('open');
        var dragged = $(this);
        dragged.css('z-index', '1000');
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {
        var dragged = $(this);
        dragged.css('z-index','1009');
    }
});

$('.hoverable').droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) {

        var target = $(event.target);

        var newElem = target.next().append('<div id="spacer" style="display:block; height:30px;width:100px;background-color:yellow;"></div>');

        newElem.on().droppable({
            over: function() {
                console.log('sdfsd');
            },
            tolerance: "touch" 
        });

    }
});

<body>

          <div class="draggable"></div>

        <div class="hoverable"></div>

        <div class="d"></div>

</body>

.draggable{
    width:100px;
    height:30px; 
    background-color:gray;

}

.hoverable{
    width:100px;
    height:30px; 
    background-color:red;

}

.spacer{
    width:100px;
    height:30px; 
    background-color:yellow;

}
```

The JsBin is here...

http://jsbin.com/golel/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your calls to `$('.draggable').draggable()` and `$('.hoverable').droppable()` are happening on the current DOM, so those functions are not executed on new DOM elements.  You somehow need to trigger these functions on new elements as well.  (If you're only worried about dynamic drop regions, you can ignore this aspect for the `draggable()` call.)

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
function makeDroppable(selector) {
  $(selector).droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) {
      var target = $(event.target);
      var newElem = target.next().append('<div id="spacer" style="display:block; height:30px;width:100px;background-color:yellow;"></div>');

      makeDroppable(newElem);
    }
  });
}

makeDroppable('.hoverable');
```

Comment: Matt,  I tried to put this code in my jsBin problem is it just triggers the bit under var newElem as soon as the spacer shows. I need it to only do something when I hover over the spacer. Are we talking about the same problem?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the problem then, sorry!